Use WLS on difference of data to calculate slope, and OLS for intercept
I have a sequence of data observed in the past X days, which I want to assign higher weights to more recent ones so it makes sense to use WLS over OLS.
However, does it makes sense to use WLS to just calculate the slope, where I run the regression on the day-to-day change of x and y (i.e. "first order derivative"). Then, I use the OLS approach to calculate the intercept?
Pros/Cons? Or does it statistically make any sense at all?
